Is there any way to display all rows that satisfy both given filtering expression in two rowFilters with same user,same catalog,schema and table name
How do we implement it [Role1 has RLS on country=US, Role 2 has RLS on country=UK, a user may have either role1, role2 or both, and if he has both then user should see rows for both US and UK] in opa rego code.
let us consider user1 has role1 and role2 with same catalog,schema and table names with differnt parameters like UK and US,By default opa rego code will combine both basically an AND operation is done and we get no values but is there any way to just display all rows that has country US and country UK(simplifies that as like the result of OR operation without explicitly giving OR condition manually).
package trino

import future.keywords.in
import future.keywords.if
import future.keywords.contains

default allow := true

user_roles = {
  "postgres": ["admin"],
  "user": ["data_scientist","admin"],
  "user1": ["my_role", "role1"]
}


table_resource := input.action.resource.table

rowFilters contains {"expression": "country = 'US'"}
if {
  table_resource.catalogName == "postgresql"
  table_resource.schemaName == "postgres"
  table_resource.tableName == "customers"
  "my_role" in user_roles[input.context.identity.user]
}

rowFilters contains {"expression": "country = 'UK'"}
if {
  table_resource.catalogName == "postgresql"
  table_resource.schemaName == "postgres"
  table_resource.tableName == "customers"
  "role1" in user_roles[input.context.identity.user]
} 

I dont know how to get rows that satisfy both filters as output as im getting no values due to default AND but i need it like default OR without explictly giving OR or is there any way to get rows atleast that satisfy one filter.
